# How to change class of specified <td>?

Tags: javascript

```js
function change() {
  var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
  var tds2 = tds.className;
  console.log(tds);
  for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
    if (tds[i].className === "marked") {
      tds[i].className = "UNmarked";
    } else {
      tds[i].className = "marked";
    }
  }
}

function generTab(rows, cols) {
  var html = "<table id='tb01'>";
  for (var i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
    html += "<tr>"
    for (var j = 1; j <= cols; j++) {
      html += "<td class='marked' onclick='change()'>" + "</td>";
    }

    html += "</tr>"
  }
  return html + "</table>";
}
```

```css
td.marked {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: solid thin black;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
}

td.UNmarked {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: solid thin black;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  Number of rows:
  <input type="text" id="rows" />


</div>
<div class="line">
  Number of cols:
  <input type="text" id="cols" />
  <span class="error"></span>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Generuj" id="gener" />
</div>
<div id="scene"></div>
```

I'm generating table by my own, and I want to change class of specified `<td>` by clicking on on it. The problem is that when I click on whichever `<td>` it is changing the classes of all of them, but I want to change that `<td>` class which I click.

Comment: Some html and css would be nice to have a working snippet!…

Comment: Could try to add an `id` to one of the `td`, then then use `getElementById` instead of `getElementsByTagName`. Hard to say without the code.

Comment: Your actual code doesn't generate your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can do some thing like the following with a single class:

```js
var tds = document.querySelectorAll("td");
tds.forEach(function(td){
  td.addEventListener('click', function(){
    this.classList.toggle('marked')
  });
});
```

```css
td {
   border: 1px solid lightgray;
   padding: 10px;
   font-size: 20px;
}
.marked{
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks it was what i needed!

Comment: Why not `this.classList.toggle('marked')` ? I'd also suggest creating a single function that is shared for the handler instead of creating a new one for each element.

Comment: @CleverBoi19, please notice the update in the answer which makes use of `.toggle` without using any `if` condition which is really nice observation by Crazy Train......thanks.

Comment: @CrazyTrain, you are right about `.toggle()` and I have updated the answer accordingly.......thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add `click` event listeners to all the `td` elements and implement a simple `onClick` function which adds/removes the desired css class.

```js
const tds = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('td'));

const onClick = ({ target }) => { 
  tds.forEach(td => td === target ? td.classList.add('active') : td.classList.remove('active'))
}

tds.forEach(td => td.addEventListener('click', onClick));
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
  
  <table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you've written should be toggling the class of all `td`s in the document. I believe you're trying to change the class of the td that is being clicked. To do that, try something like (apologies in advance as I'm on my phone):

```
function change(e) {
  let td = e.target;
  if (td.classList.contains('marked')) {
    td.className = 'UNmarked';
  } else {
    td.className = 'marked';
  }
}
```

and be sure that that change is bound as the click event for each td.

Comment: It can not define "e", but yes. Im trying to change class of the td that is being clicked

Answer (score -1):

If you can use jQuery...

```
$("td").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("marked")
        .toggleClass("UNmarked");
});
```

Comment: I prefer to use JS. I do not know JQuery at all.